# getting \u200b in json return from php rest service

Tags: php, android, json, rest

I created a rest service in PHP for communicating with android, the application is working fine but the thing is I am getting \u200b at the end of json returned by PHP rest service.My PHP code is as given below

```
private static function getNewConnection()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "exam") or die ("Could not select database");
    return $con;
}
public static function getNewDetails()
{
    $dbh = MyClass::getNewConnection();
    $data =(object)array(
                 'users' => MyClass::getJsonArray("SELECT * FROM user", $dbh)
    );
    mysqli_close($dbh);
    return $data;
}
```

I am getting the json like

```
[
  {
    "userId": "11",
    "userName": "john"
  }
]â€‹
```

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: can you tell us which json library are using to parse db objects to json string?